# on SQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

Learning SQL Query optimisation, was going through [this tutorial link](https://dzone.com/articles/sql-query-optimization-and)

Mentioned below is as-is SQL query from the tutorial,

Un-Optimized Query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name > 100
```

Optimized Query

```
SELECT * From table_name WHERE column_name >=99

SELECT column_name1, column_name2 From table_name WHERE column_name >=99
```

Trying to understand, how is the 3rd query optimised than the 2nd one as they both make a comparison and only the `>` / `=` varies?

Comment: Given that `>=99` and `>100` will give different results, this seems like a really bad example; did the tutorial author mean `>=101`?

Comment: "Query 2 will look for value 100 in database then will perform action on value 100. Query 3 will not look for value 100" I believe there is mistake as it's cleraly the other way around. But I guess the whole point is "the more selective you are in your query the faster it would go (as in "less record taken and less columns retrieved")

Comment: Reading through, that is a really poorly written article. From bad English ("runs more faster and has better performance") to poorly chosen examples, and some frankly baffling assertions with no explanation (why would defaults make inserts faster?). My advice: leave well alone and find a better tutorial.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: In general, the solution to such a query is to examine and compare the execution plans for both query. **If** those statements were doing the same thing I would expect any modern DBMS to generate the same execution plan. I agree with the others that that "tutorial" is not worth reading

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : i am on `mysql`, yeah, will switch to other tutorial! :)

Answer (score 0):

Query 4 is optimised because lesser load of data will travel in the network between your application/server and database when you are not selecting all the columns(i.e. faster I/O). It's quite negligible when you have limited number of rows and no large objects like CLOB or BLOB. It starts to make a difference when you are working with a huge data-set in the table.

Query 2 and Query 3, there shouldn't be any significant difference.